# Difference between PyObject and object? (and possibly other definitions)

Tags: cython

I'm looking for a precise definition of the following for the purpose of programming in Cython:

- PyObject
- `object`
- Python object (as in "cannot convert X to Python object")
- Cython object

and the differences between these and a shared object compiled from C/C++ code that Cython generates from a `.pxd` and `.pyx` file defining an extension type.

**Edit:** I meant the code one writes in C/C++ and the code that Cython generates. Compiling regular C/C++ code and Cython generated code will produce a different binary, right? What does Cython do that makes it worth not writing everything in C/C++?

(bonus: definition of PyObject in CPython source code)

I've tried learning cython from the official tutorials and reading the documentation, but this confusion is a major obstacle to further development.

Comment: It would be a legit question to ask for differences between `PyObject *` and `object` in Cython. However, adding shared object (i.e. so-file) into the mix doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Well, there’s a difference between writing code in C/C++ and letting Cython generate it for you. The same compiler will create two different binaries. What’s the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you manipulate in Python code is ultimately a "Python object". These are implemented/represented in C by the `PyObject` structure that contains

1. A link to the another `PyObject` defining the type.
2. A reference count (to decide when it can be destroyed)
3. Some data, which can be basically anything, depends on the type of the object and is what makes it useful.

(Almost) all Python programs should work in Cython. Thus, if you compile a Python program in Cython you're still using Python objects. Cython generates some C code that manipulates these Python objects using the Python C API (i.e. using them as `PyObject*`). You mostly don't need to worry about what it's actually doing since it behaves the same as in Python - they're automatically reference counted etc.

In Cython you can then specify types (e.g. `cdef int`, `cdef char*` or perhaps a C struct). These are directly C types, and using them appropriately gives you extra speed. They aren't Python objects (and so may need to be converted to Python objects if you want to pass them back to pure Python code - Cython knows how to do this for some, but not all, C types). The general rule in Cython is that everything is  Python Object unless you say otherwise.

The `object` keyword in Cython is a way of specifying a type to be a Python object. (It also has its usual meaning from Python where it represents the type of an "empty" object). You don't normally have to use it since Cython assumes things are a Python object by default unless you tell it otherwise.

A "Cython object" refers to an object with a type defined as `cdef class Something`. These are still Python objects, however the "useful data" is stored in a way that Cython knows about which makes it quick to access from Cython. Often this useful data is composed of basic C types (like `int` or `char*`).

If you really want you can use the C `PyObject` directly in Cython, calling the C API functions yourself. If you do this then Cython *does not* take care of the reference counting for you (as it would do if you'd declared the type as `object` or simply not declared it). For this reason you shouldn't usually do this.

---

There's no real difference between writing C code yourself and letting Cython generate it - you can do anything it can do. It does take care of *lots* of tedious and hard-to-get-right stuff for you, and this is the main advantage.